# How to print rdlc report without Report Viewer or any print dialog in C# .Net

Tags: c#

```
can i print .rdlc report without using report viewer or any print preview dialog Box?
```

-I want to Print directly without Print Preview or Printer Dialog Box.
-Please Guide me i am new in this type of work in C#.
-please provide me code for this work if any one have.

Comment: crystal report or RDLC report ?

Comment: @Vicky S -Rdlc Report.

Comment: please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx

Comment: The Link above will print the report to an .xps file and prompt you for the file location. If you specify the name of a printing device, it will print the report to that device directly. I want Directly print

Answer (score 1):

This may useful for you,
[Printing a Local Report without Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)

[How to directly print rdlc report without showing PrintDialog() in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716657/how-to-directly-print-rdlc-report-without-showing-printdialog-in-c)

Thanks,
Christo

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
            report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Your.Reports.Path.rdlc";
            report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", getYourDatasource()));
            report.PrintToPrinter();
```

kindly refer the link [How to directly print rdlc report without showing PrintDialog() in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716657/how-to-directly-print-rdlc-report-without-showing-printdialog-in-c)